# django filter using two lists for two columns

Tags: django

I have a scenario where I have to match first name and last name against a list, but I cannot find a solution. For one record it works fine but for list it is not working.

```
user.objects.filter(firstname ='john',lastname='doe') it is working fine.
```

but in case of list:

```
list1 = ['john','mark','john']
list2 = ['doe','waugh','peter']
```

john peter is not available in db. but due to first match__ in, it brings the third     record. 
Also, in db it has many records but it should return john doe and mark waugh. It should skip john peter.

```
user.objects.filter(firstname__in =list1,lastname__in=list2)
```

Comment: Why should it skip John Peter?

Comment: ohn peter is not available in db. but due to first match__ in it brings the third

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is using [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object:

```
query = Q()
for firstname, lastname in zip(list1, list2):
    query |= Q(firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname)
user.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: Does this give a different result than `reduce(_or, [Q(fn=fn1, ln=ln1), Q(fn=fn2, ln=ln2), ...])`? Seems like it does for me, but can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is correct, since the __in is not an exact query.

you have two choices:

1) switch to exact queries for each tuple (firstname, surname) as you did in the first example

2) chain an [exclude filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) on the second query, to avoid displaying entries that aren't both in list1 and list2