# Django ORM filter with two __in

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm having model with two field.
product_ids_list = [1,2,3,4]
selling_prices_list = [65, 89, 93]
And length of product_ids_list and selling_prices_list are same.

I'm able to perform below ORM filter for one product_id and it's corresponding selling price like this.

```
product_instances = Product.objects.filter(product_id=product_ids_list[0], selling_price=selling_prices_list[0]).first()
```

But how to do perform ORM filter with just one DB call with product_ids_list and it's corresponding selling_prices_list.

```
product_instances = Product.objects.filter(product_id__in=product_ids_list, selling_price__in=selling_prices_list).first() (This isn't working in the expected way)
```

Comment: Is product_id field IntegerField or ForeignKey? I believe selling_price filed is int.

Comment: Share more information on what the problem is, and what do you expect the result to be.

Comment: @Aadarsha product_id is a ForeignKey and selling_price is Int

Comment: @Demetris I want to perform something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847109/sql-dynamically-select-using-two-lists-for-the-where-clause . In addition I want to filter first element in every QuerySet

Answer (score 0):

If **product_id** is **ForeignKey** and **selling_price** is **IntegerField** then the filter code would be:

```
product_instances = Product.objects.filter(product_id__id__in=product_ids_list, selling_price__in=selling_prices_list).first()
```

As you are supplying list of IDs, we would have to compare product IDs. If we filter with **product_id__in**, it compares Product object with IDs in the list.

***Suggesstion:*** *It would be better to have ForeignKey field name as **product** instead of **product_id** to avoid confusion like the above ORM filter.*

Comment: This isn't gonna work please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894201/django-filter-using-two-lists-for-two-columns. The only thing I need to add is first() in every Q() in queryset. I'm not able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: If you want to filter using or operator i.e; `product in` or `selling price in`, then it would be like this:
`product_instances = Product.objects.filter(Q(product_id__id__in=product_ids_list)|Q(selling_price__in=selling_prices_list)).first()`

Else, please clarify the problem using sample input you have and the sample output you want to generate.